# echo -e cat: argument line too long

Tags: bash, echo, cat

I have bash script that would merge a huge list of text files and filter it. However I'll encounter 'argument line too long' error due to the huge list.

```
echo -e "`cat $dir/*.txt`" | sed '/^$/d' | grep -v "\-\-\-" | sed '/</d' | tr -d \' | tr -d '\\\/<>(){}!?~;.:+`*-_ͱ' | tr -s ' ' | sed 's/^[ \t]*//' | sort -us -o $output
```

I have seen some similar answers here and i know i could rectify it using find and cat the files 1st. However, i would i like to know what is the best way to run a one liner code using echo -e and cat without breaking the code and to avoid the argument line too long error. Thanks.

Comment: Is there a reason you're using `echo -e`? Do you _really_ want to change escape sequences inside of your text files into the characters they represent?

Comment: In general, the Right Way to avoid an argument-list-too-long error is to use a command which runs multiple commands when the arguments won't all fit on one. `find "$dir" -name '*.txt' -exec cat '{}' +` is a typical example.

Comment: yup i need to change the escape sequences. ;(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, with respect to the most immediate problem: Using `find ... -exec cat -- {} +` or `find ... -print0 | xargs -0 cat --` will prevent more arguments from being put on the command line to `cat` than it can handle.

---

The more portable (POSIX-specified) alternative to `echo -e` is `printf '%b\n'`; this is available even in configurations of bash where `echo -e` prints `-e` on output (as when the `xpg_echo` and `posix` flags are set).

However, if you use `read` without the `-r` argument, the backslashes in your input string are removed, so *neither* `echo -e` nor `printf %b` will be able to process them later.

Fixing this can look like:

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
  printf '%b\n' "$line"
done \
  < <(find "$dir" -name '*.txt' -exec cat -- '{}' +) \
  | sed [...]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
grep -v '^$' $dir/*.txt | grep -v "\-\-\-" | sed '/</d' | tr -d \' \
  | tr -d '\\\/<>(){}!?~;.:+`*-_ͱ' | tr -s ' ' | sed 's/^[ \t]*//' \
  | sort -us -o $output
```

If you think about it some more you can probably get rid of a lot more stuff and turn it into a single `sed` and `sort`, roughly:

```
sed -e '/^$/d' -e '/\-\-\-/d' -e '/</d' -e 's/\'\\\/<>(){}!?~;.:+`*-_ͱ//g' \
  -e 's/  / /g' -e 's/^[ \t]*//' $dir/*.txt | sort -us -o $output
```

Comment: thanks. that helps but how would i include ehco -e for interpretation of backslash escapes or is there a better solution? sorry i'm still learning.